# Multithreaded bundle and service instances

Tags: java, multithreading, osgi

Assume I have 3 bundles **A**, **B** and **B1**. Bundle **A** is the starting point of my application. Bundle **B** provides the API of the service used by **A**. Bundle **B1** is an implementation of the service.

Basically, bundle **A** has a set of records that it processes one after the other. There is no order for processing the records.

I would like to improve performance of my application by processing subsets of records concurrently.

I thought about two different ways: multiple instances of bundle A and, bundle A with multiple threads.

AFAIK, it is not possible to add multiple instances of the same bundle (i.e. same OSGi identity) in an OSGi container.

Regarding the second possibility, each thread created by bundle **A** would have its own identity. And the service exported by **B1** needs to know the identity of the thread that uses it. Thus, I thought a `ServiceFactoy` would fit here. However, I've read that once a service instance is obtained by a bundle, it is cached. Therefore, all the threads would get the same service instance.

Am I right? If yes, what is the "right way" to implement this model? Feel free to propose me a completely different approach that is more OSGi friendly.

Thanks,
Mickael

---

**EDIT:**

Another possibility would be to modify the Service interface to allow the service's consumers to pass their identity to the Service. The Service would then become "stateless" and the use of ServiceFactory would not be required. However, the fact the identity is required is an implementation detail (i.e. it is required only for this specific implementation), therefore for future implementations, the parameters added to the interface would not be used. This is why I prefer not to touch the interface.

Comment: What do you mean by "identity of the thread"? Do you use a technology? If I were you, I would try to pass the same identity (guess setting a thread local variable) in the new threads.

Comment: I mean some hard coded identity set during thread creation. This identity would be used to configure the service instance. Using the same identity would not help me since the returned service instance should be configured differently per thread.

Comment: You might be interested in this RFC: https://github.com/osgi/design/blob/master/rfcs/rfc0195/rfc-0195-ServiceScopes.pdf However, I think you should still thinking of refactor the service in the way that it can handle requests coming from multiple threads. E.g.: Register a custom Factory as the service instead of registering the service itself. In that case instantiation will be in your hands and you can pass identity information via the parameters of the factory method.

Comment: I have nothing against refactoring the service. The problem is that the ServiceFactory contract explicitly indicates the OSGi container will cache the returned Service for the requesting bundle. Therefore, the first thread will be the one that triggers the service creation, and the service instance will be configured for this thread. However, the other threads will receive the same service instance which will cause issues.

Comment: The link you gave me seems to be what I need. Do you know if it has been implemented in Eclipse Gemini/Spring DM?

Comment: I know how ServiceFactory works :). I meant that you should refactor a bit and not register the Service that you registers now but register a Factory as an OSGi service. By Factory I mean custom class that was written by you. Clients would than get the Factory and call the getInstance() method on it. If you use a connection pool, it would be important to either implement a createInstance() function that always instantiates your object or a retrieveService that should be called in your finally block.

Comment: I think Prototype scope should be implemented on the OSGi-core level. This means that if it is implemented, it must be in Equinox, Felix or Knopflerfish. You may find information about it in their documentation. If not, you can ask the maintainer of the RFC about it via e-mail.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean but this way I lose the transparency when working with services (i.e. I need to add a call to getInstance in the consumer while it's done by the OSGi container when regular ServiceFactory is used). I need to see what would be the impact. Regarding the prototype scope, I didn't found it in 4.2, I will look in later versions but I need to take into consideration the fact I use Eclipse Gemini, maybe it's not compatible with newer OSGi version. Thank you!

Comment: With a Factory you it would be clear for the user what and why happens. It is not always the best option to hide logic from programmers. Consumers of the Service will still be able to catch the event when the provider is not available anymore as the Factory itself is a service as well. If your consumer is implemented with a technology like DS, you would not be able to use the prototype scope anyway.

Comment: The factory being mentioned is the same approach as using a Datasource.  It is a pooling mechanism used for resource management.  The factory gets to manage how many service instances exist and you can reuse them, like a JDBC Connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right way" in OSGi is to provide a service that is stateless.

As you have already discovered, the ServiceFactory concept does not help you, it only differentiates between invoking bundles, not threads, contexts or anything else that can be a container for state.

If your service *must* keep track of state, the best way is to make that explicit and provide some kind of parameter to pass the state. The RFC that Balazs mentions is another option in the future (provided it makes it into the specification).