# OSGI two instance of the same service

Tags: java, eclipse, service, osgi, equinox

I do have a service "A" this service will be consumed from 11 other components. If I check all available services via the osgi console I do see only one instance and all 11 components consuming this service.

But for some strange reason, I don't understand, two of the components don't use the same service instance. If I debug I see two different IDs. How can this happen? 
And I am not doing anything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598163/multithreaded-bundle-and-service-instances).

I solved the problem by setting "This component is immediately activated" within eclipse. But as I red [here](http://thecarlhall.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/when-to-immediately-activate-an-osgi-component/), this is not the purpose of this checkbox. So maybe someone can explain how this happened in the first place and why it was fixed with this enabled.

Comment: Do you use Declarative Services? Also, do you mean that the java object ID is different?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos yes indeed, may I not?

Comment: As a design principle, your service should be able to tolerate not being a singleton. As the answer says, various things might cause it to be re-initialised. If you need to store global state, you could consider other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Declarative Services, the DS runtime may under certain circumstances re-instantiate your service, usually because some services it depends on have appeared/changed/got removed and the references are static. Check to see that *all* sites where service A is used are either static, or dynamic with both bind/unbind methods.